# tensorflow is not installing correctly: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to confirm my tensorflow installation and I get this.

```
(tf) C:\Users\User>python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 37, in 
> from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

Any suggestions?

Comment: How, EXACTLY, did you install tensorflow?

Comment: pip install tensorflow from the miniconda setup

Comment: Could you give details of operating system and hardware pls? I've found miniconda problematic in some environments for installing tensorflow (particularly on Windows and Raspberry Pi). Using a non-conda approach (venv + pip install...) can be more reliable.

Comment: Could you please follow the instructions mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link to install tensorflow in your system.